# svm returns the same accuracy no matter which dataset used

Tags: scikit-learn, kernel, classification, svm, cross-validation

I have 50 different pairs of training and test sets. No matter which pair I choose I always get 0.5 as the accuracy. So something is definitely off. I would really appreciate it, if you could check that I am using everything correctly. The data consists of vectors that have to be classified correctly (either 1 or 0).

[image]
[image]

Below is my code:

```html
train_set = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../train_set7.csv', sep=',')
test_set = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/.../test_set7.csv', sep=',')

train_set_values = train_set.iloc[:,0:51]
labels_train = train_set['50']
vects_train = [i for i in train_set_values.values]
test_set_values = test_set.iloc[:,0:51]
labels_test = test_set['50']
vects_test = [i for i in test_set_values.values]

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1000)
clf.fit(vects_train, labels_train)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
pred = clf.predict(vects_test)
accuracy_score(labels_test, pred)
>0.5

clf.score(vects_test, labels_test)
>0.5
```

Comment: Try to adjust the C parameter, maybe for the algorithm is the best quess to always predict the same value (0 or 1), did you check that?

Comment: You should change the kernel from `linear`to `rbf`.

Comment: @AntoineDubuis I have tried all kernels including rbf. It's the same result.

Comment: Thank you @PV8. I will try different values for C.